# How to wash very muddy sports boots?

Tags: cleaning, sports

After playing soccer on muddy pitches, are there any recommendable ways of getting rid of the mud stuck between the studs and generally on the shoes/boots/trainers/sneakers?

Comment: Not a hack, but practical: When my son was little and played football, they had a big concrete ring (maybe a short section of sewer pipe) with a stand-pipe in the middle with 4 taps and a drain. There were also handled scrubbing brushes attached with chains. The little kids sat on the edge of the ring and scrubbed their boots with brush and water. They weren't allowed into the changing rooms until their boots were clean.

Answer (score 4):

- Easiest way to get rid of the mud from bottom of the shoe is to let
  the mud dry, then beat your shoes on some hard surface, all the stuck
  mud will be removed.
- After that, you can remove the lace and rinse it in warm water and thereafter clean the shoes with the paper towel.

Answer (score 3):

The UK TV show 'Dragon's den' featured an invention by a 15-year-old schoolboy, which is now just coming to market, with the support of an almost unprecedented three of the 'Dragons' from the show.

[Boot Buddy](http://www.bootbuddy.com/dragons-den.php) was designed specifically for the task you describe.

Failing that, the old standard solution of a hosepipe or outdoor tap [faucet] & a scrubbing brush has worked for many people for many years.

*For those who don't know the show*
Dragon's Den has a panel of 5 highly successful businessmen & women, known as the Dragons [not least for their ferocity in grilling less-capable candidates], who invite potential new inventors & business startups to make their case for investment into their company. The Dragons invest their own money & time in the successful applicants' businesses, & of course, share in the rewards if the business grows.
The show has actually turned out some extremely successful, multi-million pound businesses in its 16-year lifespan.
I understand Canada also has a version of the show & it was also re-named to Shark Tank for a US version, so it may be better-known than I originally thought.

Comment: Hmm interesting... £16 RRP

Comment: Might be a bit expensive for what is essentially a water bottle with a brush on the end, for sure, but you cannot deny it is specifically intended for the OP's purpose ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't looking for perfectly clean shoes, just walk through a shallow puddle (or embrace your inner child, and splash around). The water very quickly rinses off the mud, and you can do it in shallow water that won't leave your shoes soaking wet. This is most easily done when the mud is still wet.

Answer (score 0):

I lean them sole up at like 45 degrees and hit them with garden hose and a high pressure nozzle.

[image]